# Reversing a domain name string in Java

Tags: java, strings, interview-questions

> Given a dot separated domain name, reverse the domain elements.

Example:

```
codereview.stackexchange.com -> com.stackexchange.codereview
google.com -> com.google
```

I just wanted some suggestions to improve my code. Or if you can suggest a better way, please do so.

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class ReverseDomainName
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the domain name to be reversed");
        String domain = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        ReverseDomainName obj = new ReverseDomainName();
        String reversedDomainName = obj.reverseDomainNameString(domain);
        System.out.println("The reversed Domain Name = "+reversedDomainName);
    }

    public String reverseDomainNameString(String s)
    {
        String reverse1 = "",word ="" ;
        int i;

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,"."); 
        int len = st.countTokens();

        /*
         * The check is performed so that instead of com.stackexchange.codereview.
         * we can get the proper com.stackexhange.codereview  so no
         * extra dot
         */

        word  = st.nextToken();
        reverse1 = word+reverse1;


        for(i=1;i<len;i++)
        {
            word = st.nextToken();
            reverse1 = word +"."+reverse1;

        }

        return reverse1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`StringTokenizer` is an OK solution, but I think that `String.split()` would lead to a less verbose solution.

Here is a Java 8 solution that uses `split()`:

```
public static String reverseDomainNameString(String s) {
    List<String> components = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\."));
    Collections.reverse(components);
    return String.join(".", components.toArray(new String[0]));
}
```

Without Java 8's `String.join()`, though, the solution would be more tedious.  Note that it might be a good idea to ensure that the string is non-empty, otherwise `components[0]` (or `st.nextToken()` in your original solution) would crash.

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) return s;
    String[] components = s.split("\\.");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (int i = components.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        result.append(components[i]).append(".");
    }
    return result.append(components[0]).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### One big point

From the JavaDoc for `StringTokenizer`

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although **its use is discouraged in new code**.<sup>[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)</sup> (emphasis mine)

If even Oracle discourage its use, I suggest you avoid it like the plague.

A Java 8 `Stream` based solution:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public static String reverseDomain(final String domain) {
    final String[] tokenized = domain.split("\\.");
    return IntStream.range(0, tokenized.length)
            .map(i -> tokenized.length - 1 - i)
            .mapToObj(i -> tokenized[i])
            .collect(joining("."));
}
```

Here we use `String.split` to tokenize the `String`. Using `Pattern.splitToStream`, which snazzier, makes for uglier code as there is no way to reverse a `Stream`.

We then `Stream` the range `[0, tokenized.length)` and use `map` to get the indices in reverse.  Finally we just need to get the item at the index from `tokenized` and use [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) to reconstruct the reverse domain.

As always, unit tests are **a must**:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class AppTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> parameters() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"", ""},
                {"google.com", "com.google"},
                {"codereview.stackexchange.com", "com.stackexchange.codereview"}
        });
    }

    private final String input;
    private final String expected;


    public AppTest(String input, String expected) {
        this.input = input;
        this.expected = expected;
    }


    @Test
    public void testReverseDomain() {
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, App.reverseDomain(input));
    }

}
```

Comment: Good catch about that remark in the JavaDoc. Interestingly, it's "discouraged", but not quite _deprecated_. And to my knowledge, no deprecated method has actually been removed, to date. I think it's just saying that the `Enumeration`-based interface feels "old".

Comment: Some people still swear by `StringTokenizer` because it does not use regex to parse the `String`. Sure, it's not really recommended in this day and age, and choosing a 'discouraged' class in the name of performance smells of premature optimization, but it's still a valid point.   Also, I don't think there's an easy equivalent of [`StringTokenizer.nextToken(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken-java.lang.String-) in the 'modern' approaches... if anyone so happens to *really require* it.

Comment: @h.j.k. Would be interesting to see some micro-benchmarks between the two. My suspicion would be that any regex equivalent to a simple match that can be used in `StringTokenizer` would be equally fast. As far as `hasNextToken` goes - `Pattern.splitAsStream().iterator()` covers that and much more. Pre-Java8 a `Scanner` is an `Iterator` so covers both regex and non-regex use cases... In short: no excuses!

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree too. :) BTW the method I linked too is a way to 'dynamically' adjust the delimiters while parsing the `String`, it may be beneficial in certain use cases where one needs to 'step through' the `String` with a variety of delimiters depending on the positioning.

Comment: @h.j.k. see [`Scanner.useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.util.regex.Pattern-) - this allows for the same and to switch between basic/regex patterns. Agreed that this functionality isn't available on `splitAsStream` - but the same might be achieved with the correct regex; depending on how dynamic you need the pattern to be.

Comment: @h.j.k. I have [posted a benchmark](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113139/22486) for review. But it seems to indicate that `split` and `splitAsStream` are rather faster than `StringTokenizer`.