# Benchmarking String splitting - follow-up

Tags: java, strings, benchmarking

This is a follow-up from: [Reversing a domain name string in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113033/22486)

There are a number of ways of splitting a `String` using a delimiter in Java, especially now with Java 8:

1. [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) (not recommended)
2. [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) (recommended replacement)
3. [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with delimiter
4. [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with `Pattern`
5. [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-)

With the methods that take a `Pattern`, the `Pattern` can be pre-compiled and stored or created dynamically.

`StringTokenizer` is not recommended, but apparently [still used](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113033/reversing-a-domain-name-string-in-java/113052#comment209048_113052). The other methods, to my eye, all look fairly similar. Obviously some lend themselves better to some situations than others, but it's all too much, so I decided to leverage JMH to see which one is faster.

I created a project from the Archetype [as recommended](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), and added the following benchmarks:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class MyBenchmark {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private String warandpeace;


    @Setup
    public void prepare() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.");
        try (final InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/boris/benchmark/warandpeace.txt");
             final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            warandpeace = reader.lines().collect(joining());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testSplit(final Blackhole blackhole) {
        for (final String s : warandpeace.split("\\.")) {
            blackhole.consume(s);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testStringTokenizer(final Blackhole blackhole) {
        final StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(warandpeace, ".");
        while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            blackhole.consume(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testScannerString(final Blackhole blackhole) {
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(warandpeace).useDelimiter("\\.")) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                blackhole.consume(scanner.next());
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testScannerRegex(final Blackhole blackhole) {
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(warandpeace).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\."))) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                blackhole.consume(scanner.next());
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testScannerPrecompiledRegex(final Blackhole blackhole) {
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(warandpeace).useDelimiter(pattern)) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                blackhole.consume(scanner.next());
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testSplitAsStream(final Blackhole blackhole) {
        Pattern.compile("\\.").splitAsStream(warandpeace).forEach(blackhole::consume);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testPrecompiledSplitAsStream(final Blackhole blackhole) {
        pattern.splitAsStream(warandpeace).forEach(blackhole::consume);
    }

}
```

For review is my usage of JMH. I don't have much experience with JMH and this will hopefully get me on right path to writing correct benchmarks, so nitpicks are also good!

com/boris/benchmark/warandpeace.txt is the full text of War and Peace as made available by [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/).

I'm not going to post the [full output](https://gist.github.com/bmorris591/07aa7a0b4cdf02925ade) of the benchmarks here, unless otherwise requested, but here is the result:

> ```
> # Run complete. Total time: 00:47:13
>
> Benchmark                                  Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
> MyBenchmark.testPrecompiledSplitAsStream  thrpt  200  355.893 ± 6.618  ops/s
> MyBenchmark.testScannerPrecompiledRegex   thrpt  200   75.811 ± 1.311  ops/s
> MyBenchmark.testScannerRegex              thrpt  200   76.246 ± 1.427  ops/s
> MyBenchmark.testScannerString             thrpt  200   75.690 ± 1.279  ops/s
> MyBenchmark.testSplit                     thrpt  200  358.356 ± 4.745  ops/s
> MyBenchmark.testSplitAsStream             thrpt  200  348.294 ± 7.435  ops/s
> MyBenchmark.testStringTokenizer           thrpt  200  145.767 ± 2.585  ops/s
> ```

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
- RAM: 16GB DDR3 1333 MHz

---

My first post had a stupid mistake in the benchmarking code (see revision history for details), please disregard the earlier results which put `Scanner` with a `String` at ≅1 op/s.

Answer (score 1):

Your benchmarks look fine.

Instead of using the BlackHole you could probably have simply returned the number of sentences although that would have created an (unlikely) window for optimisations and using the BlackHole is safer.